# Loopback interfaces is not pinging on both pcs for packet tracer

Tags: cisco, ping, ip-address, packet-capture, loopback

I am trying to ping my isp ip address (aka loopback 1) and loopback 10 to PC1 and PC2. Whenever I ping both ip addresses and default gateway from pc1 to pc2 it works. However, when I'm trying to ping my isp ip addresss (1.1.1.1) and loopback 10 ip address (10.10.10.238) on my cmd the request times out.

I also did the ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 loopback1 command on my router1.

Does anyone know what I can do to make sure that both loopbacks can be pinged on my cmd for packet tracer?

Anyways here is a screenshot of my topology and interface brief.
[Topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVVNI.png)

[sh ip int brief](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8da3.png)

Comment: Ping is bidirectional. Both routers need a route to the other router's loopback address.

Comment: do you know what route I should type on the CLI?